# Self-invoking function with Golang

Tags: go

Could not easily find info on how to create a self-invoking func in Golang.

My end-goal is to export a map from a file, something like this:

```
type Foo struct {}
type Bar struct {}

var TypeMap map[interface{}]string;

func selfInvoking(){

  TypeMap = map[interface{}]string{
    Foo: "foo",
    Bar: "bar"
   }
}()
```

how can I go about exporting a populated map like this from a file in Go? It's basically for one-time configuration.

Using the pattern above, I will get

> "unused variable TypeMap".

Comment: I think you want to use the package's init function.

Comment: @ain yeah I think you are right - see Dmitry's answer, but if there is a way to create self-invoking func I would love to see it thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 ways to execute initialization code in `GO`:

- [Constants](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#constants)
- [Variables](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#variables)
- [The init function](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init)

In your case you can use last two.

Variable:

```
var TypeMap = map[interface{}]string{
    Foo{}: "foo",
    Bar{}: "bar",
   }
```

The init function:

```
var TypeMap map[interface{}]string

func init(){
  TypeMap = map[interface{}]string{
    Foo: "foo",
    Bar: "bar",
   }
}
```

In any case be careful with initializers and do not use them for any complex or `io` code.
Initializer are not very good for unit testing and errors handling/logging.

Comment: Ah ok, I don't realize you could create a variable outside a func like that

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to achieve but this compiles at least

```
import (
    "fmt"
)
type Foo struct {}
type Bar struct {}

var TypeMap map[interface{}]string;

func selfInvoking(){

  TypeMap = map[interface{}]string{
    Foo{}: "foo",
    Bar{}: "bar",
   }


}


func main() {
selfInvoking()
fmt.Println(TypeMap)
}
```

Comment: who is going to call main? I am not..I need the selfInvoking func to be called right after it's declared, I don't think this accomplishes that? The reason I have the func in the first place is to populate the exported map TypeMap.

Comment: I think instead of main, maybe init? Does init automatically get called in a file?

Comment: yes, sorry I didn't understand what you ment in the question :)

Comment: no problem, in JS, self-invoking funcs are relatively common, to create isolated scope, or recursion, or what not

Comment: ah, right.  JS is kinda different as it isn't compiled.   JS might be the worlds most popular language but personally I find it's semantics and syntax a bit quirky!

Comment: Node.js is awesome - dynamic languages can be a lot of fun. Node.js + TypeScript is killer, *gradual typing* is a good paradigm. So far Golang is aight but a little restrictive. I started with Java, then moved to Node, now trying Golang.